# Spotlight Woes! Can't search, can't reindex, can't find

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, spotlight

Help!

Spotlight stopped working ... if I go to spotlight search (top right), it just hangs.

Same with Apple-F in Finder ... it causes Finder to hang for a minute or so. Cannot search.

I went to Spotlight Sys Prefs. Switching to Privacy Tab takes like 10 seconds.
Then If I try to add a drive to Privacy tab, it either crashes SysPrefs, or gives me this:

[image]

So I tried all kinds of things I found online, like

```
sudo mdutil -a -i off
sudo mdutil -i on
sudo mdutil -a -E -v
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist
sudo mdutil -aEv

sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100
sudo rm -rf /Volumes/0/.Spotlight-V100
```

etc...

I tried rebooting from a backup System drive & repairing permissions from Disk Utility.

But it still doesn't work!

Help!
OSX 10.6.8

---

**Update**: some more weirdness:
The plist for mds tries to launch `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds`

But if I look inside `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/`

I see that `Support` is just a hardlink to `Versions/Current/Support`

`Support -> Versions/Current/Support`

Then looking inside `Versions` I see only one folder called `A` and inside that are
`Headers, Metadata, Resources, Support` -- and inside `Support` is:
`mds,mdworker,mdworker32,mdwrite`

Should I edit my `com.apple.metadata.mds.plist` to launch `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/mds` ??

What the heck is this `A` folder???

Comment: Does anything interesting show up if you search for `md` or `spotlight` in `system.log` in Console?

Comment: Yes, actually! This repeats over and over: `com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[31908]): posix_spawn("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Support/mds", ...): No such file or directory
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds[31908]): Exited with exit code: 1
com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.metadata.mds): Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds`

Comment: But it stops after I do `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.metadata.mds.plist`

Comment: Frameworks can contain multiple versions in directories like A, B, etc. com.apple.metadata.mds.plist should already launch mds. Can you try upgrading to 10.7 or upgrade installing 10.6 again?

Comment: What does `ls -l /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/Metadata.framework` show?

Comment: @Mark: >`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   24 Sep  5  2011 CodeResources -> Versions/A/CodeResources  `
>`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   24 Nov 23  2011 Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers  `
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   25 Sep  5  2011 Metadata -> Versions/Current/Metadata  `
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   26 Sep  5  2011 Resources -> Versions/Current/Resources  `
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   24 Sep  5  2011 Support -> Versions/Current/Support  `
`drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  102 Jun 13 17:38 Versions
`