# Merging Contacts Manually between IOS and Windows - Need Last Modifed Date

Tags: iphone, ipad, contacts

I've read through all of the descriptions for applications on IOS and haven't found any contact export program that will preserve the last modified date on contacts. My employer has contacts stored in an iPhone, iPad and Outlook and has updated different contacts in different places. I wanted to dump everything in to excel and just work from there, but most importantly none of the contact export tools I have tried on IOS contain the last modified date. Without that I would be manually checking thousands of contacts! Any suggestions on apps or techniques?

She is not using iCloud because when she first tried it the contacts were duplicated and notes were lost. We are moving to an exchange server but I have to manually clean up the contacts first.

Comment: It's unlikely the data is available, and we can track this on a parallel thread if you wish... http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54458/spotlight-woes-cant-search-cant-reindex-cant-find

Comment: Well this is in the API for contacts: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kABPersonModificationDateProperty

And there are apps that can list contacts via last modified/creation date: https://itunes.apple.com/app/id294325239

So I'm wondering if someone has an app that can actually export and leave that piece of data intact.  This is all going in to excel, so formatting wouldn't be a huge issue as long as I could somehow break it down to columns.

Comment: You're right. Another thread also exposed the data on OS X in terms of some databases, so if it doesn't get any traction, ping me in two days and I'll gladly hang a bounty on it to see if there are apps or a reasonable workaround to get at the data.

Comment: Does this Q&A shed any light on your question? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115551/